# Setting an animated .gif as the desktop background on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, desktop-customization, animated-gif

I have an animated .gif I created using Photoshop CS4, but I can't get animation on my desktop although I can set it as a background from the context menu by opening it in Internet Explorer.

How can I set an animated .gif as the desktop background on Windows 7?

Comment: I can't imagine working with an animated background.

Comment: I guess there is only option of dreamscene to [put video as on our background](http://www.comptips.org/2012/02/set-videos-as-your-desktop-background.html)... This will help us to move wallpapers as background on windows 7. And also there are few videos available which will exact look like animated images.

Comment: Dearmscene takes A LOT of CPU because it has do continuously play the movie.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See the free [BioniX Desktop Wallpaper Changer](http://www.bionixwallpaper.com/index.html):

> BioniX Desktop Wallpaper Changer is
>   the most popular desktop wallpaper
>   changer/wallpaper manager for Windows.
>   It is FREE and jam-packed with
>   features that no other concurrent
>   wallpaper manager can offer!
>
> Compatible with all Windows systems -
>   From Win95 to Vista and Windows 7, all
>   operating systems are supported.
>
> BioniX Desktop Wallpaper Manager
>   supports the following image formats:
>   JPG (JPEG, JFIF, JPE), PNG, GIF
>   (static and animated), BMP, ICO, WMF,
>   EMF. Just drag and drop any image over
>   BioniX's interface and it will be
>   automatically included in the
>   playlist.

Comment: Now BioniX Wallpaper Changer comes with a dedicated tool called BioniX Desktop Animator: http://www.bionixwallpaper.com/downloads/Animated%20Desktop%20Wallpaper/index.html

Answer (score 8):

Windows 7 added a "multiple picture Slideshow" feature to the desktop background settings.

You are not able to make an animated GIF work normally, but you can break up the GIF into single frames and the slideshow feature will run it as if they were still together.

Remember to order the frame numbers with zeros when naming them (e.g. `name001`, `name002`, `name003` instead of `name1`, `name2`, `name3`) to avoid the dreaded `1, 10, 11, 2, 20, 21,` ordering.

Remember to uncheck the "random" box at the bottom and adjust the delay down to 10 seconds (the minimum). Obviously speed leaves much to be desired with the minimum delay between frames of 10 seconds, but at least you will get your moving background again.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly and animated gif, but you could take a look at [Enable DreamScene in Any Version of Vista or Windows 7](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/19525/enable-windows-dreamscene-in-any-version-of-windows/)

Comment: thanx mate will convert my gif's to video nice one

Answer (score 1):

Im using Windows XP and my gif started playing on my background when i put 'set as desktop background'.I had to go to 'Desktop' and put it on Stretch in stead of Tiles since it looked weird having a lot playing at once.

Comment: Question is about Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

In order to get an animated gif to appear as your desktop, which is what I imagine you're trying to do, you'd have to upload it somewhere and use active desktop, which I think died around windows ME.

Comment: currently using win 7 and is there any solution for it other than active desktop?