# How can you put animated gifs on your desktop

Tags: windows-7, desktop

> How can you put animated gifs on your desktop? (in windows 7)

I have wanted to do this for a long time. Whenever I put a gif on my desktop it never animates. Is there any software I could use? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you talking about the desktop background image, or the "preview image" for the file icons of the GIFs?

Comment: @IQAndreas background desktop image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have read about this in other forums as well as in here and this is what they suggest. Check out this forum topic:

[Setting an animated .gif as the desktop background on Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/153075/setting-an-animated-gif-as-the-desktop-background-on-windows-7)

[How do I set a moving animated .gif image as my desktop b.g./wallpaper](http://www.sevenforums.com/customization/331339-how-do-i-set-moving-animated-gif-image-my-desktop-b-g-wallpaper.html)